# Android KSoap2 xml response

Tags: android, asp.net, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I have a web-service in .NET i am using ksoap2  but i am not getting the xml response.
Is there any way by which i can call the service and get the xml response.?

my code is

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("MobileNo", "7777777");
        request.addProperty("strstartdate", "2012-01-23");
        request.addProperty("strenddate", "2012-01-30");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
            new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    //  envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

Thankx

Answer (score 0):

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

After this line, you can use `androidHttpTransport.responseDump` to get response in XML format.

Answer (score 0):

add two statements that is

```
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
```

just before `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`

and just after it add   `String theXmlString = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;`